# What is the best way to deploy a paid app that gives a service to other apps

Tags: android, service, coordinates

I'm a newbie to android. I want to write a paid app (not free) that gives a service to other apps, very much like the location service that apps can request to receive repeatedly. My app is intended for augmented reality and translates the items u see on the screen (coming from the camera in real-time)  to real world coordinates. So any app wanting real world coordinates of items in the video captured by the camera would receive these coordinates from the app I will write.
I want my app to send out information (messages) every second and the apps that want to use this information would request to subscribe to the wanted message and then receive it every second as it is sent out.
Hopefully I explained this clearly.
Thanks in advance for your help in this issue.
Gil

Comment: Getting into paid services is a big venture, you are going to want to do a lot of research on this. Broadcasting an RSS feed (or similar) is one thing, getting paid for it is another.

Comment: I mean an app you download that is paid for. I was thinking that anyone that wants to use the features my app can do will have to download it from the store. Other apps that want to use my apps service will need my app installed as well.